# if $B^3=C^3=BC=\mathbb I$ can we say anything about $L$ if $e^L=B+C?$

Tags: matrix-exponential, unitary-matrices, graph-laplacian, hermitian-matrices

My intuition on matrix exponentials, hermitian matrices, unitary matrices, adjacency matrices, and Laplacian matrices is not superb now.

For example, let $A$ be a matrix with $A^2=\mathbb I$.  $A$ may be the adjacency matrix for a bijective graph; in my example it's a permutation matrix.  I think then that $A$ is unitary, and we can also can relate a hermitian matrix $K$ to $A$ in the equation:

$$e^K=A\tag 1$$

as $K=\mathbb I-A.$

However, if instead we have two other permutation matrices $B$ and $C$, both of order $3$ and not of order $2$, with $B^3=C^3=BC=\mathbb I$, can we say anything about the matrix $L$ in the similar equation:

$$e^L=B+C?\tag 2$$

My guess/desire is for $L=2\mathbb I-B-C,$ but I wouldn't know how to attack this.  I believe the Lie product formula would help, but I don't trust my background on these topics yet.

Comment: Why does $K=I-A$ satisfy $e^K=A$? For example, I'm not getting this if $A$ is the adjacency matrix of a single edge.

Comment: You're right I think I might have missed some factors.  I think it's $A=e^{i\frac{\pi}{2}(\mathbb I-A)}$.